# Allowing the user to download a csv on Google Earth Engine application

Tags: google-earth-engine

I've been able to put together a simple Earth Engine app that essentially generates zonal statistics for the country the user picks. I realize I can't use the Export function in the app, so I'm currently plotting the results in a table chart.

The only way right now for the user to get the results in table format is clicking the arrow on the corner of the table, which opens a new window, where one has to wait a few seconds for the "Download CSV" button to appear.

My question is: is there a way I can move this "Download CSV" button to the main app panel, thus saving the user from having to look for it in a new page where it isn't even there for a couple of seconds?

Here's the current app: https://guilhermeiablo.users.earthengine.app/view/landcoverstats

And here's the full code:

```
var mainPanel = ui.Panel({
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('vertical',true),
  style: {width: '30%', padding:'20px'}
});

ui.root.add(mainPanel);

var titleLabel = ui.Label({
  value: 'FABLE Zonal Statistics Extractor',
  style: {fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '30px', color: 'black'}
});
mainPanel.add(titleLabel);


var countryLabel = ui.Label({
  value: 'Pick a country'
});
mainPanel.add(countryLabel);

var countries = ['Azerbaijan','Armenia'];

var countrySelect = ui.Select({
  value: 'Azerbaijan',
  items: countries,
  style: {width: '100%'}
});
mainPanel.add(countrySelect);


var layerLabel = ui.Label({
  value: 'Pick a layer'
});
mainPanel.add(layerLabel);

var layers = ['COPERNICUS LandCover 2019'];

var layerSelect = ui.Select({
  value: 'COPERNICUS LandCover 2019',
  items: layers,
  style: {width: '100%'}
});
mainPanel.add(layerSelect);

var calculateButton = ui.Button({
  label: 'Calculate statistics',
  //add the corresponding function to onClick
  onClick: {},
  style:{width:'100%'}
});
mainPanel.add(calculateButton);


//LAND COVER STATS FOR ROAD DENSITY PIXELS

//Get road density pixels
var density50 = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-guilhermeiablo/assets/World_50km_RoadDensity').filterBounds(geometry);
Map.addLayer(density50, {color: 'purple'}, 'RoadDensity Pixels')

//Copernicus landcover
var landcover = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019').select('discrete_classification');
var palette = ['282828','ffbb22','ffff4c','f096ff','fa0000','b4b4b4','f0f0f0','0032c8','0096a0','fae6a0','58481f','009900','70663e','00cc00','4e751f','007800','666000','8db400','8d7400','a0dc00','929900','648c00','000080']

var roadcover = landcover.clip(density50)
Map.addLayer(roadcover,
   {min:0, max:200, palette: palette},
 'Road Land Cover 2019')
 
//Function for calculating area
var calculateClassArea = function(feature) {
    var areas = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(landcover)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'class',
    }),
    geometry: feature.geometry(),
    scale: 100,
    maxPixels: 1e10
    })
 
    var classAreas = ee.List(areas.get('groups'))
    var classAreaLists = classAreas.map(function(item) {
      var areaDict = ee.Dictionary(item)
      var classNumber = ee.Number(
        areaDict.get('class')).format()
      var area = ee.Number(
        areaDict.get('sum')).divide(1e6).round()
      return ee.List([classNumber, area])
    })
 
    var result = ee.Dictionary(classAreaLists.flatten())
    var grid_id = feature.get('grid_id')
    return ee.Feature(
      feature.geometry(),
      result.set('grid_id', grid_id))
}

var gridAreas = density50.map(calculateClassArea);

var classes = ee.List([0,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,111,112,113,114,115,116,121,122,123,124,125,126,200])
var outputFields = ee.List(
    ['grid_id']).cat(classes).getInfo()
 

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(gridAreas,'grid_id').setChartType('Table').setOptions({
          title: 'Parcel Characteristics)',
        });
var chartLabel = ui.Label({
  value: 'Click on the arrow on the top-right corner of the table to see the download option',
  style: {fontSize: '12px'}
});

mainPanel.add(chartLabel);
mainPanel.add(chart);
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [ee.FeatureCollection.getDownloadURL](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-getdownloadurl) and make a callback function to update a ui.Label. For example:

```js
var mainPanel = ui.Panel({
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('vertical',true),
  style: {width: '30%', padding:'20px'}
});

var downloadLabel=ui.Label("")
mainPanel.add(downloadLabel)
ui.root.add(mainPanel);

var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0")
.limit(10)

function updateDownloadLabel(url){
  downloadLabel.setValue("Click to download table")
  downloadLabel.setUrl(url)
}

countries.getDownloadURL({
  format:"CSV",
  selectors:["ADM0_CODE", "ADM0_NAME"],
  filename: "mytable",
  callback: updateDownloadLabel
})
```

this simple demo gets the first 10 features from the `FAO/GAUL/2015/level0` feature collection, and prepares a url to download the table containing only the "ADM0_CODE" and "ADM0_NAME" columns. When the url is ready, the ui.Label is updated using the `.setValue()` and `.setUrl()` methods. This solution might work for you depending on how large the table is and the app's memory usage.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/79db786b76a64296b3f71125850acba6

Comment: This is just perfect, thanks!!